# Filterfunction using array instead unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to filter a huge list of items in Javascript by certain strings users can enter in an input field.

Currently I set it up in an unordered list, all of which items are hidden on page load and displayed as needed while the user types. The user then clicks on one item and a value gets stored in a hidden field.

However I was wondering if it is better for low-end devices and mobile devices to use a javascript array instead of building a 3000 item list in the HTML DOM.

like: `var gkz = [[123,test],[345,test2],[867,banana]];`

instead of:

`<ul>
<li>item1</li>
...
<li>item 3000</li>
</ul>`

Could someone show me how to create the functionality of this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/0cgbcy35/ with an array as source of items instead of a list?

Comment: Scrape the dom for all the `li` elements, store them in memory, then use `document.createDocumentFragment` to make your painting more efficient. The sorting part is clearly written out in the fiddle.

Comment: In what way does this improve efficiency since all 3000 list items have to be painted in the first place. Could you elaborate or give reasons for downvote?

Comment: Perhaps a jquery autocomplete would be better for this task? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I tried a lot of autocomplete plugins etc. - for various reasons (especially for mobile usage) dropdowns are not a good option and we want to stick to a list type like in the fiddle that does not rely on dropdowns